# error in if statement in ssrs report

Tags: reporting-services, iif

I have a ssrs report with localization, i have to check for some conditions and concatinat the
result of expression with some string which is localized, here is the code i have done

```
 =IIF(Parameters!PledgeTerm1.Value MOD 30,Parameters!PledgeTerm1.Value & "Days",Parameters!PledgeTerm1.Value/30 & "Month(s)")
```

where i want days and months to be localized, i have written the code below

```
=IIF(Parameters!PledgeTerm1.Value MOD 30,Parameters!PledgeTerm1.Value &  Code.LocalizedValue("DAYS", Parameters!Culture.Value) ,Parameters!PledgeTerm1.Value/30 & Code.LocalizedValue("MONTHS", Parameters!Culture.Value) )
```

which is not working.....

Comment: your expression look correct check you code for errors, is there any error display ?

Comment: it shows report location as invalid, if i remove the expression report works fine.

Comment: try to replace expression with =IIF(35 MOD 30,45/4 &  "b" ,"c" & "d" ) if its works then your code has errors

Comment: with the above expression report is working fine ..

Comment: Now check your Code.LocalizedValue

Comment: Please share your code for `LocalizedValue`

Answer (score 0):

A good way to address issues like this is to set up a debugging session.

- Open the report project that references the localization project's assembly.
- Open the localization project and select the menu option Debug -> Attach to Process, and scroll down the list of Processes till you find the devenv.exe instance for the report project (or the browser process if running from a report server.)
- After attaching to the report project process, set some breakpoints at the beginning of the LocalizedValue method, and then step through the code while checking pertinent values.

This should save you a lot of time when developing custom assemblies.  I think it's also a good idea to add a unit testing project to the localization project's solution, which can run tests for any/all localization methods.  Be sure to set the unit testing project as the startup project for the solution.  Then you can run the solution in Debug anytime you change something.  This will help you catch and solve a lot of issues before they get deployed.  Hope that helps!